# Ubuntu 12.04 Mozilla quicktime stream not working

Tags: vlc, plugins, quicktime

I tried to watch some trailers from apple.com but suddenly it is asking for Quicktime instead of showing the movie.
It used to work until last week, not sure if some update messed someting up.
Any way how I can test it and fix this problem.

Restricted extras are installed.
Firefox latest version. 
VLC plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

try to install from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-mplayer
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install gecko-mediaplayer
```

Then restart browser. Works for me on Ubuntu 13.04 + Firefox 21.